# Explaining a section of assembly MIPS code?

Tags: assembly, mips

We recently wrote this code in class. I went through and adding comments that explain to myself how it works. I just don't get how the loop counts the number of chars/spaces in the string. Could someone translate it to me?

```
#Comment

.data

Str:.asciiz "hello worlds"

prompt:.asciiz "The given string is: "

ans:.asciiz "\n The number of chr and spaces is = "

.text



.globl main

main:

la $a0, prompt #load string prompt into register a0

li $v0, 4 #print string commmand(prints the prompt)

syscall #executes the command


la $a0, Str #loads Str into a0 

li $v0, 4 #print string commnad

syscall #executes the command


li $t0, 0 #set t0 to 0

la $t1, Str #load Str into register t1


Loop1: #begins the loop SECTION I DONT UNDERSTAND

lb $t2, 0($t1) #loads byte into t2?

beqz $t2, Tim #if t2 == to zero go to Tim ?

addi$t0,$t0,1 #incremet t0 by 1 ?

addi$t1,$t1,1 #initialize t1 to 1 ?

j Loop1

syscall #executes the loop


Tim:
la$a0,ans #load ans into a0

li$v0,4 #print ans string

syscall #executes command


move$a0,$t0 #move t0 to a0

li$v0,1 #print int

syscall #execute command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go from the very beginning (skipping 2 syscalls before the loop):

The analyzed string is `hello worlds` located at address `Str`

`t0` will contain the number of characters in `hello worlds`. This is what we need to find and print. It is initialized by zero:
`li $t0, 0`

`t1` contains the address of the character currently processed. It is initialized by `Str` which is the address of `hello worlds` and at the same time it is the address of its first character `h`:
`la $t1, Str`

The loop begins:

iteration1:

Currently processed character is loaded into `t2`:
`lb $t2, 0($t1)`
Recall that `lb reg, offset(addr)` implies loading 1-byte value at address `addr + offset` into register `reg`. In our case, it implies loading 1-byte value at address `t1 + 0` into `t2`. `t1 + 0` is the address of current character i.e. `h`. Hence `h` is loaded into `t2`

`beqz $t2, Tim` implies jumping to label `Tim` in case if `t2` is zero. but `t2` has value `h` so it is not zero. The purpose of this check is to detect the null-terminator which denotes the end of string. As soon as we detect that null-terminator, we are all done and the loop must finish

`addi $t0, $t0, 1` - we increment our counter (the number of characters we have processed so far). `t0` becomes 1

`addi $t1, $t1, 1` - we increment the address of the character currently processed. In other words we move on to the next character of the string (we increment it by 1 because character size is 1 byte). Now `t1` has the address of the second character which is `e`

`j Loop1` - we start a new iteration

iteration 2:

`lb $t2, 0($t1)` - `e` is loaded into `t2`
`beqz $t2, Tim` - `e` is not zero so we don't jump to `Tim` and continue the loop
`addi $t0, $t0, 1` - `t0` becomes 2
`addi $t1, $t1, 1` - `t1` contains the address of third character which is `l`
`j Loop1` - start new iteration

and so on until `beqz $t2, Tim` checks that `t2` contains zero, in which case the program stops the loop and jumps to `Tim`

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you very much for typing this all out. Im bookmarking this for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

This code is counting bytes in a null-terminated C-style string.

Let's translate this to C to see what it is doing, here we're using the if-goto style mimicking assembly's flow of control.

```
Loop1:
  int ch = *ptr;
  if ( ch == 0 ) goto Tim;      // ch is $t2
  counter++;                    // counter is $t0
  ptr++;                        // ptr is $t1
  goto Loop1;
```

And if we translate that to structured programming we get:

```
while ( *ptr != '\0' ) { ptr++; counter++; }
```

Make sense?

---

As an aside, the `syscall` just after the loop does not have any of the normal syscall setup, so appears suspicious; however, to be clear, it is dead code — code located in between an unconditional jump and the next label is (almost) certainly unreachable by any flow of control of the program (we call that dead code; it should be removed — and the comment is erroneous).

---

Using `$t0` — a calling convention volatile (scratch) register — to hold the counter live across a print-style syscall is also suspicious.  Sometimes this will work but in other environments, not.  It would be more proper to use a callee-saves (preserved/non-volatile) register like `$s0`, or a memory location rather than relying on $t0 to be unchanged.